# Android cordova media plugin pause audio after a certain event

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing a simple Android app using cordova (media plugin)and visual studio 2015 which simply plays a music and I want to pause the music after a certain event is triggered.

In following code form index.js, I'm trying to pause the music after 10 seconds. But its not working,

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397704
// To debug code on page load in Ripple or on Android devices/emulators: launch your app, set breakpoints, 
// and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
var my_media = null;

(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.getElementById("playmusic").addEventListener("click", onClickPlayMusic, false);


        The musci is now getting played. Now I want to pause() the music


        setTimeout(function () {

            alert('Going to Pause');
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.pause(); // this pasue() does not work. The musci contine to play. 
            }
        }, 10000);
    };

    function onClickPlayMusic() {
        if (document.getElementById("playmusic").innerHTML == "Play" & my_media == null) {
            console.log("Playing the music");
            var src = "file:///android_asset/www/music.mp3";
            var my_media = new Media(src);
            my_media.play();

        }
    }
})();
```

If I add pausing code inside onClickPlayMusic() function, it works pretty good.

Please let me know how can I get rid of this issue.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem :

Instead of

```
var my_media = new Media(src);
```

I did

```
my_media = new Media(src);
```

So the variable become accessible from entire page.